# Связка MVVM & WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wcf, mvvm

Так и не понял в предыдущей теме, а там судя по всему никто мне не собирается больше отвечать, так что открою новую. Вопрос тот же: контракт сервиса это Model или ViewModel??? Важно то, что в контракте сервиса есть данные которые биндятся к представлению. Например тот же список клиентов. Никто кроме контракта сервиса не сможет их обновлять, а значит это ViewModel вроде как. Но в предыдущей теме меня уверяли что это Model... Так что же это??? Не хочу начать изучение MVVM с неправильной трактовки. Просто я сразу пытаюсь применить паттерн к одному своему реальному проекту, чего тянуть то...

Comment: А вы, простите за глупый вопрос, планируете отображать сам контракт?

Comment: @Monk я вроде подробно описал что я планирую отображать... Список клиентов, это в частности. Есть и некоторые другие данные, которые тоже обновляет только сервер.

Comment: Вы хотите сэкономить сущности, поэтому у вас получается путаница. На клиенте должна быть вьюмодель для отображения. А она просто должна пользоваться сервисами (и их контрактами, ага) для работы с сервером. Сами сервисы не являются ни моделями, ни вьюмоделями.

Comment: @Monk я ничего не хочу сэкономить. Я хочу сделать как правильно. Вы мне скажите как вы предлагаете обновлять данные которые может обновлять только сервис? Никто кроме сервиса не сможет обновлять их. Абсолютно никто!

Comment: Тогда, на мой взгляд, у вас проблемы с архитектурой. С какого перепою, никто не может обновить данные? Почему нельзя вызвать сервис для обновления?

Comment: @Monk что значит вызвать сервис для обновления? Клиент подключается / отключается - в список клиентов добавляется / удаляется и т.п. Как вы предлагаете это обновлять снаружи сервиса?

Comment: А откуда я знал ваш кейс, если вы про него ни слова не написали? Опишите нормально кейс, чтобы вам смогли помочь. Задавая общий вопрос, не удивляйтесь, когда получаете общий (и бесполезный) ответ. У каждого возникает своё понимание по вашему вопросу.

Comment: @Monk что? Что такое кейс? Я довольно подробно описал. Не понимаю что вам еще не ясно...

Comment: @Monk я раньше писал этот проект на WPF, но без использования MVVM, это сейчас мне захотелось переписать на MVVM. Если хотите я скину вам этот событийный проект и вы сами все посмотрите...

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сценарий_использования - или кейс. В вопросе речь только о контракте, а в коментариях появляется реальный кейс, с которым у вас проблемы - отображение клиентов.

Comment: @Monk цитирую: "Важно то, что в контракте сервиса есть данные которые биндятся к представлению. Например тот же список клиентов. Никто кроме контракта сервиса не сможет их обновлять, а значит это ViewModel вроде как.". Здесь об этом говорилось. Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Это не говорит вообще ни о чем. Сервис отдает данные, как именно ими воспользоваться - дело ваше. По идее, прямо контракт биндить никто не должен. МВВМ подразумевает отдельную ВМ под каждую хотелку.

Comment: @Monk я вас еще раз спрашиваю: если я создам этот список в отдельной ViewModel, то как сервис будет в него добавлять и удалять клиентов??? В сервисе происходит вызов Connect (подключение клиента) и еще по определенным обстоятельствам отключение клиента (таймаут, ошибки и т.п.). В этих функциях (вызываются с клиента через прокси, а обрабатываются контрактом сервиса) как раз происходит добавление и удаление из списка. Никакой другой ViewModel эти данные получить не может, только сервис. Как вы предлагаете решить эту проблему? У меня вариантов нет!

Comment: Вот это и пишите в вопрос. Если можно запросить список активных клиентов - то я бы это и сделал во вьюмодели по таймеру.

Comment: @Monk но это же очень неудобно и коряво (перекопировать целый список каждый раз? Фуу...). Таймеры вообще - зло. Если уж на то пошло в сервисе можно было бы сделать события подключения / отключения клиентов. Но дело не только в этом, это только часть проблемы. В сервисе формируется очередь задач которые разбираются клиентами из списка. А также в сервисе есть функция формирующая эту очередь и раздающая задачи, обработчики событий клиентов (решил задачу, отключился...).

Comment: Вот тут я уже не особо могу помочь, может кто другой отпишется. Я обычно работаю с простыми сервисами, которые просто отдают мне данные или обрабатывают переданные данные.

Comment: @Monk да это и есть простой сервис. Суть задачи - распараллеливание решения интеграла. У интеграла есть нижний и верхний пределы и шаг интегрирования. По заданию я должен создать очередь подзадач для клиентов из этих пределов. Вызывает функция Solve (решить), в нее передаются (ну или откуда то из представления берутся) эти самые пределы и шаг, формируется очередь, раздаются задачи клиентам. Как только клиент решает задачу он если очередь не пуста берет следующую. Если клиент отключился - он удаляется из списка клиентов, а его нерешенная подзадача возвращается в очередь.

Comment: Как только очередь пустеет - выводится результат. Все довольно просто.

Answer (score 6):

Если кратко то это модель. Модель в MVVM это вся логика которая относится к данным, что вы берёт как вы берёте и что с данным делаете всё это модель, и что там у вас внутри(WCF, EF, WebApi) уже не важно. Модель представления содержит только логику отображения данных в представлении и ничего другого и не должна знать о том какая технология у вас стоит за моделью(WCF, EF, WebApi)

Comment: Очень хорошо сформулировано, кстати.